# Remove specified number of items from Collection<T> in Java

Tags: java, collections

I'm writing a class `Shop<T>` that contains a variable `stock` of type `Collection<T>`. The class also has methods to buy from the stock and sell to the stock. Essentially, these methods just remove from and add to the stock, respectively. The stock contains items that are all of the same product, so there is no need for ordering the collection or keeping track of where items or placed or taken from. I'm having trouble with the buy method, whose header is defined below:

```
void buy(int n, Collection<T> items)
```

What I need this method to do is (1) to add one element to `items`, (2) remove one element from `stock`, and (3) repeat steps 1 and 2 `n` times. I can't figure out how step 1.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html , what exactly is the issue faced with the code ?

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't the place for us to write the code for you... Please attempt to, provide the code, and then we can answer what confuses you.

Answer (score 2):

I think this can only be accomplished with an iterator.  Something of the form:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class Shop<T> {
    private Collection<T> stock = new ArrayList<>();
    
    public Shop(T[] data) {
        stock.addAll(Arrays.asList(data));
    }

    public void buy(int n, Collection<T> items) {
    
        final Iterator<T> iter = stock.iterator();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (iter.hasNext()) {
                final T item = iter.next();
                items.add(item);
                iter.remove();
                System.out.println("Bought "+item.toString());
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Out of stock.");
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        final String data[] = {"a", "b", "c"};
        final Shop<String> s = new Shop<>(data);
        final Collection<String> inventory = new ArrayList<>();
        s.buy(2, inventory);
        System.out.println("Inventory is now: ");
        for (String str : inventory) {
            System.out.println(" "+str);
        }
    }
}
```

This will spit out:

> Bought a
>
> Bought b
>
> Inventory is now:
>
> a
>
> b